# Staggered View rows and columns are not changing

Tags: android, staggered-gridview, staggeredgridlayout

My Staggered view is implemented like this [MyApp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4uIV.png)
but it should look like this [Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyG7a.jpg)
And i'm not able to change the rows and columns If i'm changing columns its fine but if i change row more than 1, then i get invalidOrientation warning but app runs with blank Activity.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.techshiv.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private StaggeredGridLayoutManager staggeredGridLayoutManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    staggeredGridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, 2);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(staggeredGridLayoutManager);

    List<ItemObjects> staggerdedList = getListItemData();

    SolventRecyclerViewAdapter rcAdapter = new SolventRecyclerViewAdapter(MainActivity.this , staggerdedList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(rcAdapter);
}

private List<ItemObjects> getListItemData(){
    List<ItemObjects> listViewItems = new ArrayList<ItemObjects>();
    listViewItems.add(new ItemObjects("Alkane", R.drawable.one));
    listViewItems.add(new ItemObjects("Ethane", R.drawable.two));
    listViewItems.add(new ItemObjects("Alkyne", R.drawable.three));
    listViewItems.add(new ItemObjects("Benzene", R.drawable.four));
    listViewItems.add(new ItemObjects("Amide", R.drawable.one));
    listViewItems.add(new ItemObjects("Amino Acid", R.drawable.two));
    listViewItems.add(new ItemObjects("Phenol", R.drawable.three));
    listViewItems.add(new ItemObjects("Carbonxylic", R.drawable.four));
    listViewItems.add(new ItemObjects("Nitril", R.drawable.one));
    listViewItems.add(new ItemObjects("Ether", R.drawable.two));
    listViewItems.add(new ItemObjects("Ester", R.drawable.three));
    listViewItems.add(new ItemObjects("Alcohol", R.drawable.four));

    listViewItems.add(new ItemObjects("Ether", R.drawable.five));
    listViewItems.add(new ItemObjects("Ester", R.drawable.three));
    listViewItems.add(new ItemObjects("Alcohol", R.drawable.four));

    return listViewItems;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it does not have a parameter for row , basically you are specify orientation considering it as row count
use this:

```
StaggeredGridLayoutManager staggeredGridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
```